# Show that there exist $y$ s.t. $\|x\|^2- \|y\|^2- \|y\|^4+ \langle y,x \rangle+\sqrt{2 \pi} ( \|x\|^2-\langle y,x \rangle ) \le 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfiy the following codition

\begin{align}
\|x\|^2- \|y\|^2- \|y\|^4+ \langle y,x \rangle+\sqrt{2 \pi} ( \|x\|^2-\langle y,x \rangle ) \le 0
\end{align}
for all $x$ such that $\langle y,x \rangle \ge0$ and $\|x \| \le \|y\|$.

Can we establish something about the value of $\|y\|$?
In particular, I am interested in how large $\|y\|$ can be.

Also, not sure that such a $y$ exists can this be proven.

Comment: Is $x$ a fixed given vector?

Comment: @sranthrop No, $x$ is not fixed. The constraint must hold for a set of $x$. I made this more explicit.

Comment: Ok, then this is completely different from what I expected. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reduce from an $n$ dimensional problem to a $2$ dimensional one.
The condition must hold for every $x$ in the half ball
$\langle y,x \rangle\ge0$ and $\|x\|\le\|y\|$.
This means there exists $\lambda\in [0,1]$ and a unit vector $\mathbf e$, $\langle y, \mathbf e \rangle \ge0$ such that $x=\lambda\left\|y\right\|\mathbf e$.
Because your inequality only needs the norm of $x$ and the value of the inner product with $y$, let $c=\left\langle \frac y{\|y\|},\mathbf e\right\rangle$, the value of $c$ is between $0$ and $1$.
You have equivalence between
\begin{cases}
\left\|x\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^4+\langle y,x\rangle
+\sqrt{2\pi}\left( \left\|x\right\|^2 -\left\langle y,x\right\rangle \right)\\
\left\|x\right\| \le \left\|y\right\| \\
\langle y,x\rangle\ge 0
\end{cases}
and
\begin{cases}
\lambda^2\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^4
+\lambda\left\|y\right\|^2 c
+\sqrt{2\pi}\left( \lambda^2\left\|y\right\|^2 
-\lambda\left\|y\right\|^2c \right)\\
0\le\lambda\le 1 \\
0\le c\le 1
\end{cases}
Let $f(y,\lambda,c)=
\lambda^2\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^4
+\lambda\left\|y\right\|^2 c
+\sqrt{2\pi}\left( \lambda^2\left\|y\right\|^2 
-\lambda\left\|y\right\|^2c \right)$,
we want conditions on $f(y,\lambda,c)\le 0$.
Notice that because $\lambda$ and $c$ have values in closed intervals, and that $f$ is continuous,
the various maxima below are well defined with the identity
$$
\max_{\lambda,c}f(y,\lambda,c)
=\max_{0\le\lambda\le 1}\Big( \max_{0\le c\le 1} f(y,\lambda,c) \Big)
$$
Now when $y$ and $\lambda$ are treated as constants, $f$ is a linear function in $c$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\lambda\left\|y\right\|^2\left( 1 -\sqrt{2\pi}\right)\le 0$. Note that we have equality if and only if $\lambda$ is null. It follows that
$$
\max_{0\le c\le 1} f(y,\lambda,c)=f(y,\lambda, 0)
=\lambda^2\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^2-\left\|y\right\|^4
+\sqrt{2\pi} \lambda^2\left\|y\right\|^2 
$$
Now for $y$ fixed, $f(y,\lambda,0)$ is just a quadratic function in $\lambda$ with a minimum at $\lambda = 0$, therefore
$$
\max_{0\le\lambda\le 1}f(y,\lambda,0)=f(y,1,0)=
\left\|y\right\|^2\left( \sqrt{2\pi}-\left\|y\right\|^2 \right)
=\max_{\lambda,c} f(y,\lambda,c)
$$
We deduce that as long as $\left\|y\right\|^2 \ge\sqrt{2\pi}$, then $y$ fulfills the condition.

A little bit more intuitively, you restricted the norm of $x$ to be lower than that of $y$, so the magnitude of $x$ is in the order of the magnitude of $y$ (forgot the proper name in English). For $\|y\|$ large enough, everything will be dominated by the $\|y\|^4$ term, so you're guaranteed to be negative for large values of $\|y\|$.

Comment: Thank you very. Nice answer.